# Keyboard shortcut for Help|Search not working in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

**Command+Shift+/** is a standard macos shortcut:

[image]

When activated that shortcut should put the cursor in the Help|Search like this:

[image]

However this does *nothing* in RStudio. So is there a customizable shortcut? I could not find one ..

[image]

So is there a way to get that shortcut functionality?

Comment: It works for me in RStudio 1.1.383 from some locations (e.g. the Environment tab), but that shortcut is masked in the editor by "Reflow Comment".  Deleting it from "Reflow Comment" doesn't make it available in the editor.

Comment: You're right about it working in the `Environment` tab - how did you think to try that out ;)    And as you determined - resetting/changing the `Reflow Comment` did not "liberate" the OS-level setting.

Comment: I was going to tell you that you were wrong, because it worked on my first try.  Then it didn't work on my second try, so I did a little detective work...